# How can I use a declared but undefined function in C regardless?

Tags: c, function, undefined, declare

So what I want to do is I want to create a kind of framework for myself in the future but I realized I can't do something. It goes like this:

```
void whenPressedQ();
void whenPressedW();
...
void checkPressQ(){
    whenPressedQ();
    printf("Q was pressed");
}
...
void whenPressedW(){
    doThings();
}
```

Later I will define these functions and choose which of them to use.

Problem is I can't do this for the other functions if I haven't defined them below. I get an "undefined function" error. Is there any way I can solve this? I've tried using pointers to functions and check if it's null but it's the same thing.

Comment: You could comment out all of that code (with `#if 0`) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass pointers to callback functions, or wrap them in structures, then have the library pass back a pointer to a function that matches the signature later, even one that you will write in the future.  This was how the first C++ compilers implemented virtual methods of objects.

If you just want the code to compile while you’re getting around to the unimplemented functions, you can create dummy stub functions to shut the linker up.

#### Update

Here are some examples of what I mean.  Your question is somewhat ambiguous.  If what you are asking is how you can declare functions that you intend to implement later, and still be able to compile the program, the answer is to provide stubs.  Here’s a MCVE of your interface:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* In older versions of C, a declaration like void doThings() would turn
 * type-checking of function arguments off, like for printf().
 */
void whenPressedQ(void);
void whenPressedW(void);
void doThings(void); // Added this declaration.

void checkPressQ()
{
    whenPressedQ();
    printf("Q was pressed.\n"); // Don't forget the newline!
}

void whenPressedW()
{
    doThings();
}

// Stub implementations:

void whenPressedQ(void)
// FIXME: Print an error message and abort the program.
{
  fflush(stdout); // Don't mix the streams!
  fprintf( stderr, "Unimplemented function whenPressedQ() called.\n" );
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void doThings(void)
// Is nothing a thing?
{}

// Test driver:

int main(void)
{
  whenPressedW();
  whenPressedQ(); // fails;
  // Not reached.
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you want to let the program dynamically select which function to call, that is more complicated, but you can do it with callbacks.  Here’s a simple example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// This would ordinarily go in a .h file:
typedef const char*(*callback_t)(void); // The type of a callback function.
extern callback_t get_the_answer(void);

// This would ordinarily go in a .c file:
int main(void)
{
  callback_t ask_the_question = get_the_answer();
  printf( "The answer to life, the Universe and Everything is %s.\n",
          ask_the_question()
        );

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// This would ordinarily go in another .c file:
static const char* the_answer_is(void)
{
  return "42";
}

callback_t get_the_answer(void)
{
  return &the_answer_is;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please detail that a bit more? It's kind of hard to wrap my head around

Comment: Added some examples.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. While I could use your first solution (i'm not advanced enough to fully understand the second :( ), I have managed to use a different approach and made it work by using a defined function that makes a function pointer point to a function declared and defined later by the user

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting a linker error. If you are not trying to build an executable, then you can just compile and do not link. On Linux / OS X, you can pass the  `-c` flag to clang or gcc. On Windows, you can pass the `/c` flag to `cl.exe` when compiling.

You can then link the object files directly later, or build a static or dynamic library out of them.